# Python not taking in crontab

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I have tried the below command but never able to execute in crontab, any ideas?

cd /usr/store/home/build/reportdeployment/Automate_CallCount_By_Region_by_Application_Report && /usr/bin/python doReport.py -p -c Automate_CallCount_By_Region_by_Application_Report.cfg

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you execute this (as the cron user) on the commandline?
In general I would recommend to put this into a simple shell script (which can also take care of logging and so on) and call this script directly.